Vite Fastify Stripe and Render Integration: 404 Error on /api/create-payment-intent Endpoint
I am integrating Stripe payment processing into my React application using Vite, Fastify, and Stripe. However, I am encountering a 404 error when trying to create a payment intent using the /api/create-payment-intent endpoint with Render address.
------vite.config.js------
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    port: 4242,
    proxy: {
      // string shorthand
      // with options
      "/api": {
        target: process.env.VITE_RENDER_HOST || "http://localhost:5252",
        changeOrigin: true,
        rewrite: (path) => path.replace(/^\/api/, ""),
      },
    },
  },
});

------server.js------

require("dotenv").config();

// Require the framework and instantiate it
const fastify = require("fastify")({ logger: true });
const stripe = require("stripe")(`${process.env.VITE_STRIPE_SECRET_KEY}`);

// Fetch the publishable key to initialize Stripe.js
fastify.get("/publishable-key", () => {
  return { publishable_key: `${process.env.VITE_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}` };
});

// Create a payment inntenttent and return its client secret
fastify.post("/create-payment-intent", async (req, res) => {
  const { amount } = req.body;
  const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    amount,
    currency: "usd",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
  });

  return { client_secret: paymentIntent.client_secret };
});

// Run the server
const start = async () => {
  try {
    await fastify.listen({ port: 5252 });
    console.log("Server listening ... ");
  } catch (err) {
    fastify.log.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

start();



------checkout.jsx-------

const Checkout = () => {
  const setPriceState = useRecoilValue(priceState);
  const totalPriceState = parseFloat((setPriceState * 100).toFixed(2));

  const stripePromise = loadStripe(import.meta.env.VITE_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY);
  const [clientSecretSettings, setClientSecretSettings] = useState({
    clientSecret: "",
    loading: true,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    async function createPaymentIntent() {
      const response = await axios.post("/api/create-payment-intent", {
        amount: totalPriceState,
      });

      setClientSecretSettings({
        clientSecret: response.data.client_secret,
        loading: false,
      });
    }

    createPaymentIntent();
  }, []);


When using localhost, Stripe works fine. However, if I add target: process.env.VITE_RENDER_HOST || "http://localhost:5252", I get a 403 error. Is there any documentation on how to connect Render with Stripe? I can't seem to find it anywhere.
